# Implementing Searchable Recycler View in Activity - Trouble instantiating adapter object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm basing a searchable recycler view off of this amazing demo : https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo

I'm currently stuck though, trying to create a new adapter object in my Activity. The problem is that the demo is using fragments, and I would rather not use fragments, just activities. So, when creating a new adapter object, the demo calls a function called getActivity(). My problem is that getActivity is a fragment function. I was under the impression that the equivalent to the getActivity function for use in an Activity was either .this, or use Context. However, neither have been working for me.

Here is the method from MainFragment.java in the demo I am basing the my view off of:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mModels = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String movie : MOVIES) {
        mModels.add(new ExampleModel(movie));
    }

    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mModels);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Now, here is my method, called populate(), which is called by the onCreate method. I'm getting an error on the parameters of the instantiation of the new FriendDisplay:

```
private void populate()
{
    final String[] friends = new String[]{"Friend 1", "Friend 2", "Friend 3", "Friend 4", "Friend 5", "Friend 6", "Friend 7", "Friend 8", "Friend 9", "Friend 10", "Friend 11", "Friend 12"};
    int[] navigationIcons = {R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.ic_account_multiple, R.drawable.ic_magnify};

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(FriendsActivity.this));

    mModels = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String friend : friends) {
        mModels.add(new FriendModel(friend));
    }

    mAdapter = new FriendDisplay(<NOT_SURE_WHAT_TO_USE_HERE>, mModels);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

FriendDisplay takes context as the first parameter, but when I try to use context as the parameter, it gives me the error:

```
FriendDisplay (Context, java.util.List<com.revelry.adapters.FriendDisplay.FriendModel>) in FriendDisplay cannot be applied to (Context, java.util.List<com.revelry.adapters.FriendModel>)
```

So, I'm having trouble deciphering this error message and having trouble seeing what it is I need to put as the parameter argument instead. Or, should I be putting this in a different method all together?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: How did you defined `FriendModel` class? It seems you have two definitions of it.

Comment: `Context` is any activity. Your error is for the second parameter.

Comment: @StenSoft So, could the error be for something that is stored in mModels? Because I added the objects to mModels exactly how it was in the example, I'm not sure what could be going wrong with the second parameter.

Comment: @tato.rodrigo my FriendModel class is defined as the following:

``
 package com.revelry.adapters;


 public class FriendModel {


        private final String mText;

        public FriendModel(String text) {
            mText = text;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return mText;
        }

}``

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, I can't seem to figure out inline code blocks at the moment....

Comment: @tato.rodrigo you were right, I accidentally created a FriendModel class within my adapter, as well as a separate FriendModel class...so it was in fact defined twice. Not sure how I missed that, thank you for pointing that out!!